# Cauchy problem for partial differential equation, can't solve it

Tags: linear-pde, cauchy-problem, partial-differential-equations

I need to solve Cauchy problem for partial differential equation.
My equation looks like this: 
$$
3\tfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + 5\tfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial y} - 2\tfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} + 7(\tfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}+2\tfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}) = 0.
$$
and conditions look like: $u|_{x=0} = 1$, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}|_{x=0} = 3y$

**My attemps:**
First of all, I know, to solve it, we need to transform this view to canonical view, I've done this, result is here :
$$\dfrac {\partial^2 u}{\partial \eta \partial \xi} -\dfrac { \partial u}{\partial \eta}=0$$
And as I checked, this view corresponds to the canonical view of the hyperbolic equation 
(my equation is hyperbolic as D > 0)

and the replacement I did to transform initial view to canonical view is here:  (so far as I know it is needed for the further solution Cauchy problem)
$$\phi (x,y) = y-2x=c $$
$$\psi (x,y) = 3y+x=c$$
$$\eta= 3y+x  $$
$$\xi = y-2x  $$

Unfortunately, I don't know what I need to do next, I've been surfing internet and textbooks for hours,
but haven't found any good explanations or just can't understand 
I've checked similar questions on math.stackexchange, but there is no something that is relevant for my topic

I am trying to do my best, but I need some help 
It seems I need to use integrals, do some actions with them,
integrate, substitute and other stuff like that, as minimal textbooks are speaking about it, but can't find a clue for the solution

If I am right, I found function u(x,y):
$$ u(x,y)=e^{y-2x}\phi_1(3y+x)+\phi_2(y-2x) $$
Now I need to use initial conditions to find $$ \phi_1, \phi_2 $$
I firstly differentiated u(x,y) and got:
$$\dfrac { \partial u}{\partial x} = -2e^{y-2x}\phi_1(3y+x)+ \phi_1'(3y+x)e^{y-2x} -2\phi_1(y-2x) $$
Then using the initial conditions I got a system:

$$ \begin{cases}
\begin{align}
e^{y}\phi_1(3y) + \phi_2(y) &= 1 \\
-2e^{y}\phi_1(3y) + \phi_1'(3y)e^y - 2\phi_2'(y) &= 3y 
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

But now I am not succeed in getting functions $$ \phi_1, \phi_2 $$ 
can't find actions required to solve this system

Answer (score 1):

Starting from your last line:
$$\dfrac {\partial^2 u}{\partial \eta \partial \zeta} -\dfrac { \partial u}{\partial \eta}=0$$
$$\dfrac {\partial w}{\partial \zeta} -w=0$$

Where $w=\dfrac { \partial u}{\partial \eta}$.

Solve the equation :
$$\dfrac {d w}{d \zeta} -w=0$$
$$ \dfrac {d }{d \zeta}(we^{-\zeta})=0$$
Integrate:
$$we^{-\zeta}=C(\eta)$$
$$w=C(\eta)e^{\zeta}$$

Now you can solve the equation:
$$w=\dfrac { \partial u}{\partial \eta}$$
$$\dfrac { \partial u}{\partial \eta}=C(\eta)e^{\zeta}$$
Finally:
$$\boxed {u(\zeta,\eta)=\phi_1(\eta)e^{\zeta}+\phi_2(\zeta)}$$

Comment: Treat it like a first order differential equation @Denis

Comment: How did you get from dw/de - w =0 to (w*exp^e)' = 0
sorry for my writing style
I got an integral and it resulted to: w*exp^e = 0
I don't understand where operation of differentiation came from

Comment: Integrating factor method... I choose to multiply the differential equation by $e^{-\zeta}$ @Denis

Comment: I got just (w*exp^e) = 0 
I mean without a stroke

I got a photo of my doing: https://ibb.co/mzXp68G
@Aryadeva

Comment: It's a derivative you need a stroke @Denis

Comment: Look now I changed the notation  if you prefer that notation @denis

Comment: from where you got  $$ \dfrac {d }{d \zeta}(we^{-\zeta})=0$$
from $$ \dfrac {d w}{d \zeta} -w=0 $$ ?

Comment: Differentiate first equation and you will get the second one. Google it integrating factor first order differential equation.  @denis

Comment: Ok, thanks you very much. Now I need to go sleep (I live in Russia), but right away after waking up I'm going to start my trying to solve it again. Thanks you again. I think you helped me a lot. @Aryadeva

Comment: You're welcome @Denis

Comment: I have no idea how to solve it at all @Aryadeva
I have found u(x,y) but what's next I don't know. Is there a chance you will help me more?

Comment: I got u(x,y) = $$ u(x,y)=e^{y-2x}\phi_1(3y+x)+\phi_2(y-2x) $$

Comment: Try to check now that solution plug that in tthe equation and differentiate. @Denis

Comment: I added information I have gotten trying to solve the equation, check the question body, please @Aryadeva

Comment: I have done this and put the result of this action in the question body, I'll duplicate result here:
$$ \begin{cases}
\begin{align}
e^{y}\phi_1(3y) + \phi_2(y) &= 1 \\
-2e^{y}\phi_1(3y) + \phi_1'(3y)e^y - 2\phi_2'(y) &= 3y 
\end{align}
\end{cases} $$

Or you mean to differentiate first equation of this system ?

Comment: I don't see what you can do more @denis Sorry